# Sum of a series with parameter

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the value of
$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} n(n-1)x^{n+1}$$
with $|x| < 1$.

How do we proceed finding the sum within this interval of convergence of $-1 < x < 1$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: $(x^n)'' = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$ divide by $x^2$ and integrate the series twice.